# curl работает раз в 50 раз

Tags: curl, https

Имеется часть кода с curl:

```
function getdata($url)
{
  global $urls;
  foreach ($url as $key => $value)
  {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $value);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    if (getproxy() != null) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, getproxy());
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    if ($error != "")
    {
      echo "Cannot connect to http, error: " . $error;
    } else {
      $urls[$key] = $result;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
  }
  return $urls;
}
```

$url представляет из себя массив вида "id" => "url". При запуске скрипта не осуществляется соединение и $urls == null.

Получается соединиться раз в пол часа, может реже. Тогда $urls равняется тому, чему должен. С чем это может быть связано?

UPD: ссылки яндекс.маркета, рабочие, коннект к ним вегда удается через браузер.

Comment: Добавить до цикла [curl_global_init](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html), после [curl_global_cleanup](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_cleanup.html)

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, пример, как и куда добавить эти две функции? Спасибо

Comment: Конечно можно, перейдите по переведённым ссылкам

Comment: А это разве не С библиотека? Ибо у меня не получается вызвать эти функции

Comment: Да, это С, но функции идентичные для всех языков которые используют эту библиотеку, введите в поиск гугла  название функции и вторым словом добавьте ' PHP '

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема заключается не в цикле, а в маркете. У него стоит анти-парсинг защита, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Это вторично, curl надо инициализировать глобально, он так устроен. А если стоит защита, то надо менять UA, работать через пул внешних прокси итд. Что сильно выходит за рамки вопроса :) там кстати стоит какой-то прокси в настройках, и турель..

Comment: Автор, закоментируйте весь `if getproxy()...` лишнее сейчас это :)